# angular 8 crashed when importing OAS generated api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openapi

I am new to angular and construction my first angular front end to use an OAS generated angular-typescript package. The OAS is also generated from code and then used to generate the angular-typescript package (angular version 8.2.14). Then I just created a new angular project with "ng new ..." and installed the before generated package with "npm install local/dir --save". Then I imported the module in the app.module.ts with "import { ApiModule } from "package name". So far it works (but also nothing happens).

When I import he ApiModule in the @NgModule angular just stops working, no error, no debug. I tried using demo apis from HowTos, these to import without problems. So I guess that there is a problem with the generated package, everything I tried and change in the last weeks didn't help.

Maybe you have some ideas where I can start debugging. Thank you.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { ApiModule, BASE_PATH} from "@angular-schule/book-monkey-api"; // Works
// import { ApiModule, BASE_PATH} from "@jakoberpf/congstats-typescript-angular-api"; // Does not work

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  ApiModule,
],
providers: [{ provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: environment.CONGSTATS_BASE_PATH }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. When importing an using an open api or swagger generated package you have to not only import the HttpClientModule ( see [angular issue 20575](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575) ) but also provide it in the providers of the app module.

ISSUE FIXED